# Arduino Mega: How do I switch an LED's colour using the same authenticated RFID tag and using a button too?

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I'm having some issues getting my code to do what I want on my Arduino Mega.  What I'm aiming to do is to have the same RFID tag change an LED colour from red to green and when presented again from green to red.  I also want to do this with a button.  This is for a door lock so that the door can been locked and unlocked from both sides of the door.

The code below will allow an RFID tag to change the colour from red to green and vice versa but as soon as I try to test for an authenticated card it fails miserably.  Also when I try to add the button to it my code ends up getting very messy and unusable.  I've tried various things but I think my major problem is because the code sites inside the `loop` function.  I've tried `while(1)` when trying to set the LED to a particular colour but it just doesn't work properly.

This I thought would be fairly trivial to do, maybe it is, I'm just not familiar enough with this.

Can anyone help point me in the right direction which will help me move further forward with this?

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>

// constants won't change. They're used here to set pin numbers:
const int BUTTON_PIN = 2; // the number of the pushbutton pin
#define BLUE 7
#define GREEN 6
#define RED 3
#define RST_PIN 9     // Configurable, see typical pin layout above
#define SS_PIN  53   // Configurable, see typical pin layout above

// Variables will change:
String authKeyFob = "54321098765";
String card_ID="";

//int lastState = HIGH; // the previous state from the input pin
//int currentState = LOW;    // the current reading from the input pin

int buttonState      = 0;     // current state of the button
int lastButtonState  = 0;     // previous state of the button
int ledState         = 0;     // remember current led state
int rfidState = 0;
int lastRfidState = 0;
bool toggle = false;
bool cardValid = false;

MFRC522 mfrc522(SS_PIN, RST_PIN);   // Create MFRC522 instance

void setup() {
  // initialize serial communication at 9600 bits per second:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial);     // Do nothing if no serial port is opened (added for Arduinos based on ATMEGA32U4)
  SPI.begin();         // Init SPI bus
  mfrc522.PCD_Init();  // Init MFRC522 card

  // initialize the pushbutton pin as an pull-up input
  // the pull-up input pin will be HIGH when the switch is open and LOW when the switch is closed.
  pinMode(BUTTON_PIN, INPUT);
  pinMode(GREEN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(RED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(BLUE, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {

    // read the state of the switch/button:
    buttonState = digitalRead(BUTTON_PIN);

  // Look for new cards, and select one if present
  if (mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent() ||  mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial() ) {

    if(toggle == false){
      toggle = true;  
    } else {
      toggle = false;
    }

    delay(200);
  }


    if(toggle == 1){
        digitalWrite(GREEN, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(RED, LOW);  
    } else if (toggle == 0) {
        digitalWrite(GREEN, LOW);
        digitalWrite(RED, HIGH);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is to have another if statement that reads your button and toggles your toggle variable just like you do for the card.  See if you understand what's going on here:

```
void loop() {

  // read the state of the switch/button:
  oldButtonState = LOW;    //  NEED TO ADD A DECLARATION FOR THIS BEFORE SETUP
  buttonState = digitalRead(BUTTON_PIN);

  // Look for new cards, and select one if present
  if (mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent() ||  mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial() ) {

    toggle = !toggle;   // A way easier way to write the if statements you had.  
  }
  //  if the button just became pressed...
  if(buttonState == HIGH && oldButtonState==LOW){
    toggle = !toggle;  // same thing, toggle our variable. 
  }
  oldButtonState = buttonState;  // save the button state for next time


  if (toggle) {
    digitalWrite(GREEN, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(RED, LOW);
  } else {
    digitalWrite(GREEN, LOW);
    digitalWrite(RED, HIGH);
  }

}
```

See the State Change Example to see why I store the old state of the button.  I also changed that set of if statements to just set toggle to not toggle, that's an easier way to reverse a boolean value.  I also made that last else if just an else since a boolean can only have two values.  If it isn't true then it must be false.

Comment: That helped me get back on track, I had to amend my card reader code slightly.

Answer (score 0):

This is my updated version with the RFID tag working consistently with the button and LED.

```
void loop() {

  // read the state of the switch/button:
  oldButtonState = LOW;    //  NEED TO ADD A DECLARATION FOR THIS BEFORE SETUP
  buttonState = digitalRead(BUTTON_PIN);

  // Look for new cards, and select one if present
  if (!mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent() ) {

  }
  
  if(mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial() ){
    toggle = !toggle;
    delay(200);
  }

 
  //  if the button just became pressed...
  if(buttonState == HIGH && oldButtonState==LOW){
    toggle = !toggle;  // same thing, toggle our variable. 
     delay(200);
  }
  
  oldButtonState = buttonState;  // save the button state for next time


  if (toggle) {
    digitalWrite(GREEN, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(RED, LOW);
  } else {
    digitalWrite(GREEN, LOW);
    digitalWrite(RED, HIGH);
  }

}
```